# Jersey client unable to convert ArrayList to xml

Tags: java, rest, generics, jersey, jersey-client

I have developed one restful webservice using jersey and spring.

Below is the service method which servers the request by accepting the list of Login objects.

**Method in service class**

```
@POST
@Path(value = "/login")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public String getLogin(Login login);    

@POST
@Path(value = "/update")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public void updatePassword(List<Login> userList)
```

**Login** class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Login {
//some code
}
```

I am using the jersey client to consume this webservice as below.

```
loginList = ArrayList of Login objects
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/user/update");
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(ClientResponse.class, loginList);
```

But below is the exception which I am getting.

> Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class java.util.ArrayList, and MIME media type, application/xml, was not found
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:288)
>       at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:204)
>       at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:147)

But My /login i.e. getLogin method works perfectly.

I am not able to figure out what exactly is causing this issue.

Can anyone please help me what could be the wrong happening in this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use [`GenericEntity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.html) for generic types, because of type erasure. And JAXB needs to know the type. The `GenericEntity` [stores the type](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.java#GenericEntity) through it parameter. So basically, you just need to do

```
.post(ClientResponse.class, new GenericEntity<List<Login>>(list){});
```

---

#### UPDATE

complete test using Jersey Test Framework

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Login

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Login {

    private String name;
    private String password;

    public Login() {
    }

    public Login(String name, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Login{" + "name=" + name + ", password=" + password + '}';
    }
}
```

Test

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.DefaultResourceConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.WebAppDescriptor;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.TestContainerFactory;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.grizzly2.web.GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericEntity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ArrayTest extends JerseyTest {
    
   
    @Path("/login")
    public static class LoginResource {
        
        @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        public String post(List<Login> logins) {
            return new HashSet<>(logins).toString();
        }
    }
    
    public static class AppConfig extends DefaultResourceConfig {
        public AppConfig() {
            super(LoginResource.class);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
        return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public WebAppDescriptor configure() {
        return new WebAppDescriptor.Builder()
                .initParam(WebComponent.RESOURCE_CONFIG_CLASS, 
                           AppConfig.class.getName())
                .build();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void doTest() {
        List<Login> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Login("pee", "skillet"));
        ClientResponse response = resource().path("login")
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .post(ClientResponse.class, new GenericEntity<List<Login>>(list){});
        
        System.out.println("Status " +  response.getStatus());
        System.out.println(response.getEntity(String.class));
    }  
}
```

If you remove the `GenericEntity`, you will get the error.

Comment: After I have changed it to GenericEntity its goving the same exception.

Comment: Worked fine for me. Got the exception without the `GenericEntity` and worked fine with it. I'll post my whole test.

Comment: I have one method **public List<Login> getPasswords()** which returns the list in XML from webservice server. And this works perfectly. This list conversion works fine at server side. But its not working at client side. Could there be any dependency or API missing?

Comment: Shouldn't be a dependency problem. XML binding support should be included in the core framework

Comment: Initially I got the same error at the server side while converting List to xml in response for getPasswords() method. But error gone after I have added **jersey-media-jaxb** jar.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense unless you're using Jersey 2.x on the server. The code you've posted is for Jersey 1.x. Who knows maybe you are using different versions for client and server.